# Phonegap card reader plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I downloaded this plugin [Magnetic Card Reader](https://github.com/gamezj/card-reader-phonegap) thanks to my limited experience I'm having issues. I'm using a [square 3.5mm card reader](https://squareup.com/reader) the plugin according to the author is suppose to work with 3.5mm card reader. I have this code to start the card reader according to the documentations.

```
$scope.start = function () {

        function cardReaderStart(cardReadSuccess, cardReadFailure) {
            console.log("Card reader started!");
            window.plugins.CardReaderPlugin.start(cardReadSuccess, cardReadFailure);
        }

        // If OS is Android
        function cardReadSuccess(response) {
            console.log("Card number:" + response[0].card_number);

            if (typeof response[0].expiry_month != 'undefined' && response[0].expiry_month != null) {
                console.log("Expiry month:" + response[0].expiry_month);
            }

            if (typeof response[0].expiry_year != 'undefined' && response[0].expiry_year != null) {
                console.log("Expiry month:" + response[0].expiry_year);
            }
        }

        //If OS is iOS
        function cardReadSuccess(response) {
            console.log("Card number:" + response['card_number']);

            if (typeof response[0].expiry_month != 'undefined' && response[0].expiry_month != null) {
                console.log("Expiry month:" + response['expiry_month']);
            }

            if (typeof response[0].expiry_year != 'undefined' && response[0].expiry_year != null) {
                console.log("Expiry month:" + response['expiry_year']);
            }
        }

        function cardReadFailure() {
            console.log('Please try again!');
        }

    };
```

the problem is that after I click the $scope.start and then I proceed to swipe the credit card in the square card reader nothing happens.

I'm wondering what am I doing wrong? or if you guys know any other card reader plugin I can use.

Thank you :)

Comment: Any error trace? cordova.js file included in HTML? Plugin code invoked inside deviceready event?

Answer (score 0):

I had written working code for this, Please Click [Here](https://github.com/KumarSunil007/phonegap-jack-reader-plugin), Currently it is perfectly working for Android, Soon I am going to release for IOS. If you still have any query, please comment below for your queries.